# ngx-loading add label in black screen

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm using **[ngx-loading](https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading)** and working very well.

**any.component.html**

```
<div class="my-container">
    <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ 
      backdropBorderRadius: '14px', 
      backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.87)',
      fullScreenBackdrop: 'true'
      }">
    </ngx-loading>
</div>
```

I wanna know if is possible add labels in black screen. Something like image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite easily just by setting the z-index on the label, that way it will show in front of the black screen.

```
.text {
  z-index: 2000;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(50% + 40px);
}

<div class="my-container">
    <ngx-loading [show]="true" [config]="{ 
      backdropBorderRadius: '14px', 
      backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.87)',
      fullScreenBackdrop: 'true'
      }">
    </ngx-loading>

    <span class="text">Here is some text</span>
</div>
```

Here is a StackBlitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7wwp3m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this component support text from their documentation. What you could do is

```
<div class="spinner" *ngIf="spinnning">add some text</div>
```

The show/hide is controlled by `spinning`, or a variable passed from your spinner service.

The style of the spinner is controlled by class `spinner`. You can find tons of implementation of the spinner on the internet. Ex. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Comment: Thanks for you help but ngx-loading working very well, in my project. I try spinner before but need add others lot code for not get conflits.

Comment: But you might not be able to add stuff to `ngx-loading`, since the component isn't open for injection.